Golang get Http method from events.APIGatewayProxyRequest
I am implementing a Lambda in Go that needs to be able to access the HttpMethod (type) (ie. GET, POST, etc.). This is due to the need to use a switch statement in the Handler to access the correct function.
I have tried using the api gateway with the template for passing the entire request and also tried it with no template. I also used the lambda URL (bypassing the API Gateway).
The attributes I used are event.HTTPMethod and event.RequestContext.HTTPMethod. I used to know a way to convert the events.APIGatewayProxyRequest to a standard HttpRequest but can't seem to remember it. I am stuck at this moment.
func Handler(c context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
log.Println("in handler")
log.Println(c)
log.Println("entire event object")
log.Println(request)

log.Println("request context http Method")
log.Println(request.RequestContext.HTTPMethod)
log.Println("request http Method")
log.Println(request.HTTPMethod)

switch request.RequestContext.HTTPMethod {
case "GET":
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "message": "Get is fine",
    }, nil
case "POST":
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "message": "Post is fine",
    }, nil
}

return nil, nil

Both the events.HTTPMethod and the event.RequestContext.HTTPMethod are empty (strings)
Any Ideas? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance for all help.

event.HTTPMethod is a string type and so are the methods in net/http, so you should be able to make constructs like if event.HTTPMethod == http.MethodGet or directly pass the event.HTTPMethod to functions that expect a method.
If anything gives you trouble in that regard, it might be that the method variables in net/http are const strings whereas event.HTTPMethod is just a string.

event.HTTPMethod is empty

:o  Then idk. Other then to note that this would be expected to be empty if the lambda is called in any context other than by API Gateway, but I'm betting you already knew that. I'll leave this to folks smarter than I.
